# In NextJs inside getStaticProps fetch function not working

Tags: next.js

I am trying to fetch the data from this demo URL, but I am getting an ERROR

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  };
}
```

**Output**
[image]